# Simplifying complex equation with square root

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to  solve for either $x$ or $y$ the following equation, but the square roots are giving me real problems. Any help is very welcome:
$$
F=\frac{A+Bx+C(x^2+y^2)+\sqrt{(A+Bx+C(x^2+y^2))^2-4Dy^2}}{A+Bx+C(x^2+y^2)-\sqrt{(A+Bx+C(x^2+y^2))^2-4Dy^2}}
$$

Comment: Use $F\cdot \frac {q+r}{q+r}$ for $q=A+Bx+C(x^2+y^2)$ and $r=\sqrt{q^2-4Dy^2}$

Comment: If you multiply the top and bottom by $(stuff) + \sqrt(stuff)$ then you won't have any square roots on the bottom.  The top will get messy but you have to hope that it can be simplified.

Comment: Thanks, that really simplifies the denominator, but the numerator gets extremely messy and still with square roots that don't let me solve for $x$ or $y$...